# member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type with partial class

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I have defined a partial class with a property like this:

```
public partial class Item{    
    public string this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            if (Fields == null) return null;
            if (!Fields.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                var prop = GetType().GetProperty(key);

                if (prop == null) return null;

                return prop.GetValue(this, null) as string;
            }

            object value = Fields[key];

            return value as string;
        }
        set
        {
            var property = GetType().GetProperty(key);
            if (property == null)
            {
                Fields[key] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                property.SetValue(this, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So that i can do:

```
 myItem["key"];
```

and get the content of the Fields dictionary. But when i build i get:

> "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Indexers automatically have a default name of `Item` - which is the name of your containing class. As far as the CLR is concerned, an indexer is just a property with parameters, and you can't declare a property, method etc with the same name as the containing class.

One option is to rename your class so it's not called `Item`. Another would be to change the name of the "property" used for the indexer, via [`[IndexerNameAttribute]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51hfxez7.aspx).

Shorter example of brokenness:

```
class Item
{
    public int this[int x] { get { return 0; } }
}
```

Fixed by change of name:

```
class Wibble
{
    public int this[int x] { get { return 0; } }
}
```

Or by attribute:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

class Item
{
    [IndexerName("Bob")]
    public int this[int x] { get { return 0; } }
}
```

Comment: That explained it. Thank you! I will take a look at the attribute way first.